# Understanding pointers & malloc

Tags: c, pointers, struct, return, malloc

I'm currently learning the C language and I'm struggling to wrap my head around the pointers and malloc() function.

So in my book's example I have the following function defined :

```
island* create(char *name) {
   island *i = malloc(sizeof(island)); 
   i->name = strdup(name);
   i->opens = "09:00";
   i->closes = "17:00";
   i->next = NULL;
   return i; 
}
```

Then it's called like this :

```
char name[80];
fgets(name, 80, stdin);
island *p_island0 = create(name);
```

There is several things I struggle to understand in this code example:

1. What happen to the `i` variable when assigned to `malloc(sizeof(island));`, does it just temporarily stores the reference of the new memory space allocated on the HEAP ?
2. After `island *p_island0 = create(name);` , eventually what is stored in `p_island0` ? The address created by `malloc()` or was another pointer created and the value of the previous `i` variable copied into `p_island0` on the ... STACK?

Answer (score 1):

> *1. What happen to the i variable when assigned to malloc(sizeof(island));, does it just temporarily stores the reference of the new memory space allocated on the HEAP ?*

`i` stores the pointer returned by `malloc()`. Later, that is returned as the return value of the function. Dynamic memory has a lifetime equal to the program runtime (unless manually deallocated by `free()`), so the values stored into the memory area pointed by the pointer are valid and accessible after the function returns.

FWIW, point to note here, before using the return value of the `malloc()`, it's always good to check the returned value against `NULL` to avoid UB in case `malloc()` fails.

> *2. After island `*p_island0 = create(name);` , eventually what is stored in `p_island0` ? The address created by `malloc()` or was another pointer created and the value of the previous `i` variable copied into `p_island0`?*

The same pointer returned by `malloc()` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `return i;` the pointer value stored in `i` is *copied* to the variable `p_island0` in the calling function, and then `i` goes out of scope. The allocated memory never goes out of scope, it has a life-time of the full program or until you call `free` with the pointer value. Which variable is storing the pointer value doesn't matter, as long as it is the original pointer value returned by the `malloc` call.

*How* the value is returned by the function is not specified by the C specification, it depends on the compiler, operating system and underlying hardware. Most likely the stack is not involved, but the returned value is stored in a CPU register.

Comment: Perhaps extend "*pointer*" to read "*pointer value*"? As it's about "*copying*".

Answer (score 1):

1. malloc returns the address of the allocated memory block , as a void* wich is a generic pointer type, the address (like any other value) is being copied to i.
2. the address returned from malloc is being stored in p_island0.
   *the address returned from malloc is to the heap memory , the allocated memory lives untill 'free' function is being called or untill the program ends.

Answer (score 0):

**island** is probably a struct.

The function create(char *name) has its own scope

`island *i = malloc(sizeof(island));`

This statement allocates memory which is pointed by **i**.
Therefore, **i** is limited to this function's scope. This is not accessible outside the function.

However, the function returns the value(memory location) pointed by **i** which will ultimately be stored in **p_island0**.